# Insert command does not work c #

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, sql-insert

can someone please tell me what is the problem?

**Setting :**

```
dbConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\data\db.mdf;Initial Catalog=db;Integrated Security=True"
```

**class db.cs :**

```
public SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.dbConnectionString);

public object insert(String[] inserts, String table)
    {
        string query        = "INSERT INTO "+table+"";
        int dim             = inserts.Length;
        string[] valores    = new String[dim];
        string[] campos     = new String[dim];
        string camposItems  = "(";
        string valoresItems = "(";

        for (int i = 0; i <= dim - 1; i++)
        {
            string[] item = inserts[i].Split('=');
            if (i > 0)
            {
                campos[i]     = item[0];
                valores[i]    = item[1];
                camposItems  += ","+item[0];
                valoresItems += ",@"+item[0];
            }
            else
            {
                campos[i]     = item[0];
                valores[i]    = item[1];
                camposItems  += item[0];
                valoresItems += "@"+item[0];
            }
        }
        camposItems += ")";
        valoresItems += ")";
        query += camposItems+" VALUES "+valoresItems;
        query += "";

        try
        {
            using (this.conn)
            {
                SqlCommand cmdIns = new SqlCommand(query, this.conn);
                int ix = 0;
                string[] vals = new String[valores.Length];
                foreach (string val in valores)
                {
                    vals[ix] = val;
                    SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
                    parameter.ParameterName = "@" + campos[ix];
                    parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
                    parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    parameter.Value = val;
                    cmdIns.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                    ix++;
                }
                cmdIns.Connection.Open();
                //this.conn.Open();
                //object insertID = cmdIns.ExecuteNonQuery();
                object insertID = cmdIns.ExecuteScalar();
                cmdIns.Connection.Close();
                //this.conn.Close();
                if (insertID != null)
                {
                    return insertID;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex;
        }
    }
```

call function :

```
db db = new db();
String[] valores = new String[2]
     {
         "usuario=" + this.textBox1.Text,
         "clave=" + this.maskedTextBox1.Text
      };
 object insert = db.insert(valores, "usuarios_tb");
```

please help thanks...

Comment: you have to avoid sql injection. use parameterized queries

Comment: Are you getting a specific error message?

Comment: Looks like you are missing brackets for VALUES `()`. Also post the error message, Use Parameterized queries

Comment: the query is parameterized loop is responsible for building that part (@Ravi)

Comment: @newfurniturey I do not receive any error message, but does not update the table :(

Comment: if u r not getting any exception it means you have a problem in code placed above try block,so try to put that code inside your Try block for exact exception.

Comment: the call to this function is inside try / catch @Rahul

Comment: ok so try to use stopper means debugger and check each line that where it traps..

Comment: la estructura de la tabla es :

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[usuarios_tb] (
    [Id]      INT        IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [usuario] NCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    [clave]   NCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);`

maybe the problem is here?

Comment: I put a breakpoint on the line

`object insertID = cmdIns.ExecuteNonQuery();`

and I visualize the two parameters and their values ​​correctly and when I run a query with the application open, find the record. but when I close the application and open it again the record is not. @Rahul

Comment: you are mentioning that you put breakpoint on object insertID = cmdIns.ExecuteNonQuery(); but this line is commented by you ,,you are not executing ExecuteNonQuery you are executing ExecuteScaler ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code prevents a few issues you might be having:

- Using the same connection which will become disposed.
- Complexity of code has been reducdes (less if/while/for's) which makes it easier to debug.
- Use ExecuteNonQuery instead of ExecuteScalar.
- Advise: Never catch an exception if you do not handle it. No not use exceptions as a return value.
- Advise: Use the dictionary. This way you do not have to concatinate the values first, and seperate them later. You also preserve the type of the value.

Look at this:

```
public int insert(IDictionary<string, object> inserts, String table)
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO " + table + " ";
    List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
    string camposItems = "(";
    string valoresItems = "(";

    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in inserts)
    {
        if (!camposItems.EndsWith("("))
        {
            camposItems += ", ";
            valoresItems += ", ";
        }
        camposItems += pair.Key;
        valoresItems += "@" + pair.Key;
        SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@" + pair.Key, pair.Value);
        parameters.Add(parameter);
    }
    camposItems += ")";
    valoresItems += ")";
    query += camposItems + " VALUES " + valoresItems;

    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.dbConnectionString))
    using(SqlCommand cmdIns = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        cmdIns.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
        cmdIns.Connection.Open();
        return cmdIns.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

and calling it:

```
    db db = new db();
    Dictionary<string, object> valores = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"usuario", this.textBox1.Text},
        {"clave", this.maskedTextBox1.Text},
    };
    int rowsInserted = db.insert(valores, "usuarios_tb");
```

I know, this does not really answer your question, but it might help you and other to find out what is really going wrong. And perhapse, by removing complexity, it is already working (because of the Connection and ExecuteNonQuery and the extra space after the tablename) :)

Comment: but on the line `valoresItems += pair.Key;` should not be this way? `valoresItems +="@"+ pair.Key;`

Comment: Can you tell what happens? Besides that the values do not appear inside the table, do you get an exception? What is the value of rowsInserted?

Comment: Thank you very much to all, and i found the problem. The table is not updated when i close the application because the database is integrated to the solution of the project and when pressing F5 the application "touch" the database on the project of the solution not the folder /debug/data.

When I run the application from the /debug/ working properly.